# Does Hamiltonian MCMC requires modeling function be differentiable?

Tags: tensorflow, parameters, bayesian, mcmc, log-likelihood

I have read some references about Hamiltonian MCMC but didn't understand a part of that. Suppose trying to do Bayesian inference with HMC. my problem is high dimensional (e.g. more than 1000 parameter to be found). As you know there is a prior distribution and a likelihood distribution. In likelihood probability calculation we need a forward modeler to calculate the difference between observations and modeled data. My question is, can we use HMC in the case which forward modeler it not differentiable as HMC is gradient based MCMC? What other solutions exist for MCMC with high dimensional problems with non-differentiable forward modeling function?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this sounds like a general statistic question in which case this question would be more likely to attract answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Or do you need help solving this in a specific programming language (if so, please indicate the language).

Comment: Thank you Jan. I chose Tensorflow.